# Nonmoving div/navigation on joomla page

Tags: css, joomla, position

I am working on adding a navigation bar/div to the bottom of a joomla page I am working on. I want the bar to always be on top, no matter where the person is scrolling up and down, the bar should be visible.

How do I,

1. add a bar like this using joomla
2. make sure it stays at the bottom.

I know how to make it stay still

```
   position:fixed;
```

correct me if i am wrong

Do I use the add menu manager, or can I just add a div, essential I will add 3 social network Icons to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For advanced users, editing a template I recommend making a change to your template file:
/templates/TEMPLATENAME/index.php

That's the best place to put it if you want to change the template permanently.

Alternately, place the code in a module that appears on every page.

This CSS will help with the placement of the menu

```
#fixedPositionMenu {position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;}
```

Then you can have html in your module (or in the template) that looks like this:

```
<div id='fixedPositionMenu'><a href="/link1">Link 1</a><a href="/link2">Link2</a>... etc</div>
```

Comment: this CSS will fix it at the top, to pleace it at the bottom use: {display:block;position:fixed;bottom:0px;}

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps.

- Create menus using menu manager in joomla backend.
- Create module position or use existing module.

http://docs.joomla.org/Module_positions
http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_add_a_new_module_position%3F

- And publish the menu module in that module position (Bottom as per your requirement) .
- Add the CSS for your module position as fixed.